# Unlocking Server IP via Google's DisplayUnlockCaptcha over SSH

Tags: centos6, g-suite

An IP on one of my linux servers running a php script is getting a error authenticating with google's SMTP server. It's rejecting the authentication even though it's the proper credentials.

In the past I've been able to go to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/UnlockCaptcha where I was able to unlock my account if this happened however this is a linux box and does not have any front end gui.

Does anyone know of a way to unlock googles Captcha from SSH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an SSH dynamic proxy to schlep your local browser session through your server.

Run this locally:

```
$ ssh user@host -D8888
```

Then go into your browser's configuration and set it to use a socks proxy at `127.0.0.1:8888`.

Comment: System proxy doesn't work with Chrome, but setting a proxy in Firefox works.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go to the [unlock URL](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and then initiate an SMTP connection from your server. You don't have to visit the unlock URL from inside the server.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work anymore.